# How to have different build settings/phases for ad hoc and distribution build in Xcode 4

Tags: ios4, xcode4, ad-hoc-distribution

In Xcode 3 I made a few build configurations, one being Ad Hoc, one being Distribution. In each of them I could put whatever settings I wanted so I could have some settings ( or pre build scripts) run only for the Ad Hoc or for the Distribution build.

In Xcode 4 however we are stuck with Schemes, and there is only 1 "Archive" entry where you have to choose which build config it uses. So if I want to archive both Ad Hoc and Distribution builds where both have different settings there is no other way to do this but to go and change the build config "archive" uses in the Scheme, or create a 2nd scheme just for that.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this without using multiple schemes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4 still has build configurations, which you can set by clicking on the project and then the project again in the list of targets. Each configuration can have separate build settings. To conveniently build each one, you probably will have to use two different schemes.

Comment: I clarified the question a bit, I would like to not mess with multiple schemes.

Comment: Why don't you want to use multiple schemes?